# express server blank react index.html

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, rest, express

when i am running npm start blank index.html shown from build folder

my path is correct. [image: screenshot of screen]

```
app.use(cors())
  app.use(helmet())
  app.use(auth(config));
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(compression())
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jsx');
  app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'front', 'build')));
```

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'front', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

i think its happening because i am using templete engine also

Comment: Set base url for you react app like: `<base href="/dashboard/">`. Or change your express router to `app.get('/',`.